# Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate and while working on one example i am getting below error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.tieto.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at com.tieto.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at com.tieto.Hib.main(Hib.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at com.tieto.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 5 more
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="com/abc/Test.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please suggest what i wrong in this??

Comment: Put your Test.hbm.xml into the Class path and try to run it again with this change. <mapping resource="Test.hbm.xml" />

Answer (score 1):

Copy the dtd from **hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd** and **hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd** which is inside hibernate folder(path :hibernate3/org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd and hibernate3/org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd)and paste it in your hbm.xml file and cfg.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all required jar files listed below,

1. antlr-2.7.7.jar
2. commons-lang3-3.1.jar
3. commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
4. dom4j-1.6.1.jar
5. hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
6. hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar
7. hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
8. javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
9. jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
10. jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar

You looks like most concern with log related jars.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
>       at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
>       ... 5 more

As per the last few lines of the stacktrace, I think the issue is related to the connection of your database.

Please check the name `(test)`, username `(root)` & password `(abc)` of the database, you want to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

you must first, create a file with this name "log4j.properties" (and in a maven project put it in the "resources" folder - subfolder of main folder-) then put this slice of code in pom.xml:

```
<build>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <targetPath>${basedir}/target</targetPath>
        <includes>
            <include>log4j.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```